# Can't configure spatialite because it can't detect PROJ (libproj)

Tags: pip, spatialite, proj

I need to install spatialite on my system and i am installing it from source

i Got the source code as : `wget` [`https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/libspatialite-sources/libspatialite-5.0.1.tar.gz`](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/libspatialite-sources/libspatialite-5.0.1.tar.gz)

(I have PROJ installed)

then i am inside the libspatialite-5.0.1 directory and i run `./configure`

I get a very long output on the command line the last lines of which read:

`checking for library containing proj_normalize_for_visualization... no`

`checking for library containing pj_init_plus... no`

`configure: error: 'libproj' is required but it doesn't seem to be installed on this system.`

​

[Here's The Complete Command Line Output if needed for reference](https://pastebin.com/ezXD79sT)

​

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and i am in an activated virtual environment on which i installed all the dependencies for the project i am working on

​

Can someone please help me with this?

​

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same issue here, with this message:

```
configure: error: 'libproj' is required but it doesn't seem to be installed on this system.
```

Solved using:

```
apt-get update && apt-get -y install libproj-dev
```

Along with:

```
apt-get -y install build-essential pkg-config \
  libfreexl-dev  \
  libgeos-dev  \
  librttopo-dev  \
  libxml2  \
  libzip-dev  \
  libminizip-dev
```

```
./configure
```

```
.
..
...
....

==============================================================
                        IMPORTANT NOTICE
==============================================================
You have selected --enable-rttopo and/or --enable-gcp

Both modules strictly depend on code released under the GPLv2+
license, wich takes precedence over any other license.
Consequently the copy of libspatialite you are going to build
if configured this way *must* be released under the GPLv2+ license.

If you wish better preserving the initial MPL tri-license you
simply have to reconfigure by specifying the following options:
        --disable-rttopo --disable-gcp
==============================================================
```

Tested on:

```
# cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"

# uname -mor
5.4.0-65-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux

# gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```